# Prevent change "ASP.NET_SessionId" by user c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies

I tried to prevent user for changing the `"ASP.NET_SessionId"`

I tried this code:

`Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = GenerateHashKey();`

**But my `session` (`Session["userId"]`) was removed when I tried to set the cookie**

Here is some code that I tried **without** success:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Check If it is a new session or not , if not then do the further checks
    if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null && Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value != null)
    {
        string newSessionID = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionID"].Value;
        //Check the valid length of your Generated Session ID
        if (newSessionID.Length <= 24)
        {
            //Log the attack details here
            Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }

        //Genrate Hash key for this User,Browser and machine and match with the Entered NewSessionID
        if (GenerateHashKey() != newSessionID.Substring(24))
        {
            //Log the attack details here
            Response.StatusCode = 401;
            //throw new HttpException("401");
        }
        //Use the default one so application will work as usual//ASP.NET_SessionId
        Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value.Substring(0, 24);
    }
}

private string GenerateHashKey()
{
    StringBuilder myStr = new StringBuilder();
    myStr.Append(Request.Browser.Browser);
    myStr.Append(Request.Browser.Platform);
    myStr.Append(Request.Browser.MajorVersion);
    myStr.Append(Request.Browser.MinorVersion);
    SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] hashdata = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myStr.ToString()));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hashdata);
}


protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Pass the custom Session ID to the browser.
    if (Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
    {
        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value + GenerateHashKey();
    }

}
```

How to prevent the user for set session 
[image]

Comment: Very unclear what you want to achieve... Obviously you can't prevent user from sending any arbitrary data... but you still want to protect against something... What is the threat you are trying to mitigate? (Side note: there is a good chance you want to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I know that the user can set the cookie as he wants and I want to prevent it (secure issue). that the reason I tried to create my own cookie but when I tried it the session in controller become to null

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to secure your session value from tampering? If you set the value yourself, you override the session identifier and destroy the purpose of the asp session cookie.

> ASP.Net_SessionId is a cookie which is used to identify the users session on the server. The session being an area on the server which can be used to store data in between http requests.

If you are trying to solve the session fixation problem, which is the only vulnerability of asp session cookie, then you need to introduce a new cookie like this: https://medium.com/@grep_security/session-fixation-broken-authentication-and-session-management-c37ce0111bf5

Comment: But the user can still change the session and set whatever he wants